# find keywords in file, parse lines they are on, return dict

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, io

I need to find info in a file. The file has many lines, but the ones I am after look like this

```
 Initial command:
 /opt/user/program/pg.c01/l1.exe "/scratch/user/pg-18930.inp" -scrdir="/scratch/user/"
 Entering Link 1 = /opt/software/program/pg.c01/l1.exe PID=     18941.
  
 Copyright (c) 1950-2050, program, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
```

I need to parse the file for  `-scrdir="/scratch/user/"` and `PID=     18941`.

I would like to return a dictionary like this

```
dict = {"-scrdir=":"/scratch/user/", "PID":18941}
```

This should be general in the sense that I want to pass an array of things to search for i.e., -scrdir=, and/or PID and/or other, and, get returned whatever follows those keywords, if they exist, in the file.

What I have so far seems to work but seems heavy on logical statements
As a MWE I store the info in a list rather than file, and have the following

```
log = ["this is a line Initial",
   '/opt/user/program/pg.c01/l1.exe "/scratch/user/pg-18930.inp" -scrdir="/scratch/user/"',
   "Entering Link 1 = /opt/software/program/pg.c01/l1.exe PID=     18941.",
   "  ",
   "Copyright (c) 1950-2050, program, Inc.  All Rights Reserved."]
dicti = {}
phrases = ["-scrdir", "PID"]
# with open(file, 'r') as log:# would use in real situation
    for line in log:
        if any(word in line for word in phrases):
            for phrase in phrases:
                try:
                    dicti[phrase]=line.split(phrase+"=")[1]
                except:
                    pass
```

Is there a more succinct way of writing this?

A final note is that the files are generally much smaller than 1 MB, and speed is not a priority. It does not need to be fast or efficient... just elegant I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write all the specific regular expressions you want to search in your text and then combine them with the `|` alternation operator (equivalent to an OR operator):

```py
import re

REGEXES = (
    '(-scrdir)="([/\w]+)"',
    '(PID)=\s*(\d+)',
)

dicti = dict(
    [z for z in w if z != '']  # filter all empty strings in matches
    for y in filter(lambda x: x, map(re.compile("|".join(REGEXES)).findall, log))  # get all matches in a row
    for w in y  # loop over all row matches
)
```

`dicti` is:

```sh
{'-scrdir': '/scratch/user/', 'PID': '18941'}
```

It works even if you have multiple matches in a row. For example, if you have:

```py
log = ["this is a line Initial",
   '/opt/user/program/pg.c01/l1.exe "/scratch/user/pg-18930.inp" -scrdir="/scratch/user/" Entering Link 1 = /opt/software/program/pg.c01/l1.exe PID=     18941.',
   "  ",
   "Copyright (c) 1950-2050, program, Inc.  All Rights Reserved."]
```

the output will be:

```sh
{'-scrdir': '/scratch/user/', 'PID': '18941'}
```

It does not work if the text you are looking for is spread across multiple lines.